# Adding a static row to a JQuery drop down

Tags: jquery, html

I have a function which populates a drop down box, however as soon as the data is returned the first record is shown in the drop down.  There's a 'change' event assigned to this drop down so i don't want anything selected when the datas first returned.

How do i add a 'Nothing Selected' row, or even a blank row, when the drop down is loaded?

My current code is:

```
 function loadDropDown(data1) {
    var renderDrop = _.map(data1, function (val) {
    return '<option>' + val + '</option>';
    }).join(); 
    $('#mydropdown').html(renderDrop);
    }
```

And my HTML is:

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="mydropdown">
</select>
```

I tried hard coding an `<option>Select an option</option>`

Anyone know how to sort this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

Add `<option>Select an option</option>` before you add other options .

```
$("#mydropdown").html("<option>Select an option</option>" + renderDrop);
```

Comment: Thanks, i think both these answers would work but i ended up using this, didn't realize it was so simple, makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A more flexible approach would be like this:

```
    $("#ddl option").eq(0).before($("<option></option>").val("").text("Select"));
    $("#ddl")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

In this way an item can be added any where within the list.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overwriting the whole select, you can append the options.

```
function loadDropDown(data1) {
  _.map(data1, function (val) {
    $('#mydropdown').append($('<option>' + val + '</option>'));
  });
}
```